# Не работает подраздел на сайте

Tags: html, vds

захостил свой сайт с помощью vds и vesta, использовав домен .tk.
В корневом разделе создал директорию folder, добавил в неё index.html, 
Но если я захожу на сайт site.tk/folder, то вижу тоже самое,что и в site.tk.

Comment: @Denis640Kb , apache.

Comment: @Denis640Kb , прямой путь тоже не работает.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, в директории public_html у меня его вообще нет.

Comment: @Denis640Kb,linux debian 9.

Comment: Вот путь к корневому разделу, в нём лежит папка с подразделом. /home/admin/web/site.tk/

Comment: @Denis640Kb, в public_html.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, ошибочка, я использую nginx + appache.